# Is there a Savitzky-Golay filter implementation that is robust against NaNs?

Tags: python, filter, scipy

I use the scipy.signal implementation of the Savitzky-Golay filter for quick lowpass filtering of various data. I understand that the filter is a moving average over the data array, such that all values in the given averaging window are averaged.

Unfortunately, the scipy.signal.savgol_filters implementation is not rubust against NaNs.

Running

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sg

data_in = np.arange(15, dtype=float)
data_in[7] = np.nan
filtered = sg.savgol_filter(data_in
                            , window_length=3
                            , polyorder=1
                            , mode='nearest')
```

leads to

```
data_in
Out: 
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6., nan,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12.,
       13., 14.])

filtered
Out: 
array([ 0.33333333,  1.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ,  4.        ,
        5.        ,         nan,         nan,         nan,  9.        ,
       10.        , 11.        , 12.        , 13.        , 13.66666667])
```

Is there a nice, handy, ready-to-use implementation of a Savitzky-Golay filter that is somehow ignoring the NaNs instead of leaving large portions of NaN in the output (particularly for large averaging windows)?

Comment: Why are there NaNs? Why not remove them?

Comment: In the dataset that I actually want to filter, I have multiple datasets to plot vs. date. Occasionly, there is data missing for a few dates (but the other datasets have data for that date), which causes NaN in the dataset that I want to filter.

Comment: If you use an implementation for which you can specify weights for the data, you can use zero-weights for the NaNs and unit-weights for all other elements, and just replace the NaNs with an arbitrary number (it doesn't matter which).